# iOS Parse Notification Message (null) on UIAlertView

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

I'm using Parse.com to send push notification to a simple iOS web view app, but I can't seem to get it to show my message text from my JSON payload:

```
{
    "alert": "Push Message goes here.",
    "url": "http://www.google.com"
}
```

Here is my `AppDelegate.m`:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {

    NSString* notifURL = [userInfo objectForKey:@"url"];
    NSLog(@"Received Push Url: %@", notifURL);

    NSString* message = [userInfo objectForKey:@"alert"];
    NSLog(@"Received Message: %@", message);

    NSLog(@"UserInfo: %@", userInfo);

    if (application.applicationState == UIApplicationStateActive) {

        UIAlertView *alertPush = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"My Webview App"
                                                       message:message
                                                      delegate:self
                                             cancelButtonTitle:@"View"
                                             otherButtonTitles:@"Cancel", nil];
        [alertPush show];
        [alertPush release];

        objc_setAssociatedObject(alertPush, &aURL, notifURL, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC);

    }

}
```

Here is what my log returns:

> Received Push Url: http://www.google.com
>
> Received Message: (null)
>
> UserInfo: {
>       aps =     {
>           alert = "Push Title goes here";
>       };
>       url = "http://www.google.com";
>   }

Am I missing something here?

Comment: kindly show us the output of `NSLog(@"UserInfo %@" userinfo);`

Comment: @AnoopVaidya I have updated my post with UserInfo output, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you format the `UserInfo` you will see it has two keys `aps` and `url`. The `url` has value `http://www/google.com` and the value of `aps` is again a dictionary. This dictionary has a key `alert` with value `Push Title goes here`

```
UserInfo: { 
           aps = { 
                   alert = "Push Title goes here";
           }; 
           url = "http://www.google.com"; 
}
```

So you need to extract it by:

```
NSString *message = userInfo[@"aps"][@"alert"];

//First extract the dictionary with key : aps
//then extract the string with key : alert
```